# Adding optgroup in select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code which will create `select` from a `ul li menu`. I want to add `optgroup` from parent menu, but don't know how to. Here is my code:

```
// Create the dropdown base
jQuery("<select />").appendTo("#module-menu");

// Create default option "Go to..."
jQuery("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
    "value"   : "",
    "text"    : "Go to..."
}).appendTo("#module-menu select");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
jQuery("#menu a").each(function() {
    var el = jQuery(this);
    jQuery("<option />", {
        "value"   : el.attr("href"),
        "text"    : el.text()
 }).appendTo("#module-menu select");
});
jQuery("#module-menu select").change(function() {
    window.location = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#parent')
    .append($('<select>')
        .append($('<optgroup>')
            .prop('label', 'group 1')
            .append($('<option>')
                .text('option 1'))));​
```

[Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tk5Cs/)

[Another example taking data from ul.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tk5Cs/1/) Code:

```
var sel = $('<select>');
$('#parent').append(sel);

$('#menu>li').each(function()
{
    var group = $('<optgroup>')
        .prop('label', $(this).find('>span').text());
    sel.append(group);

    $(this).find('ul>li').each(function()
    {
        var opt = $('<option>')
            .text($(this).find('>span').text());
        group.append(opt);
    });
});​
```

Comment: how to get it from `ul li` :-)

Comment: now my `window.location` is not working, link is not valid. I also changed `.text($(this).find('>span').text());
` to `.text($(this).text());`